# Why does this code sometimes crash the browser?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me why this code sometimes enters an infinite loop (presumably from the while loops) and crashes the browser window? Is it something to do with `while(userChoice != randNumber)`, does this not have a sufficient end?

```
var check = function(userChoice) {
        while ((isNaN(userChoice)) || (userChoice > 100) || (userChoice < 1) || (userChoice %1 !== 0)) {
        userChoice = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 100", "It must be a whole number!");
    }
};

var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
var userChoice = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 100");
console.log(userChoice);
check(userChoice);
//Above sorts out the computer choice and sets the rules for the user choice

while(userChoice != randNumber) {
    if (userChoice > randNumber) {
        userChoice = prompt("Your number is GREATER than the computer.", "Please re-choose a number between 1 - 100");
        check(userChoice);
    }
    else if (userChoice < randNumber) {
        userChoice = prompt("Your number is SMALLER than the computer.", "Please re-choose a number between 1 - 100");
        check(userChoice);
    }
}    

console.log("Your number matches! Congratulations!");
```

This is a modification of some earlier code I had which would crash more often. Although the above code is more stable, it still does crash occasionally, although I am unable to explain the exact procedure to initiate an infinte loop.

The old code is as follows:
**(as a priority can someone tells me why this crashes? I don't see why the while loop doesn't end when the correct number is reached!)**

```
main = function() {


var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
var userChoice = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 100");
while ((isNaN(userChoice)) || (userChoice > 100) || (userChoice < 1) || (userChoice %1 !== 0)) {
    userChoice = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 100", "It must be a whole number!");
}
//Above sorts out the computer choice and sets the rules for the user choice

while(userChoice !== randNumber) {
    if (userChoice > randNumber) {
        userChoice = prompt("Your number is GREATER than the computer.", "Please re-choose a number between 1 - 100");
    }
    else if (userChoice < randNumber) {
        userChoice = prompt("Your number is SMALLER than the computer.", "Please re-choose a number between 1 - 100");
    }
}    

return("Your number matches! Congratulations!");

};
main();
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. When are you noticing an infinite loop occurring?

Comment: @MitulP91 Well it seems pretty weird. I just manged to to crash again by repeatedly putting in random numbers, minus numbers, letters and symbols. I don't suppose it could just crash if you overloaded the browser? I'm very new to this so I might just be being an idiot!

Comment: The wisest thing would be to dump this 1995-style code. Write a document with a text input, a button, and a place to output your messages. Your script will evaluate the value of the input when the user clicks the button. Users HATE prompts, and they **really** hate them coming up again and again.

Comment: @Jeffman Well yes, I would but I'm very new to this! I'm just trying to do some basic tasks with the knowledge I have so that I can consolidate it!

Comment: If you're very new to this, that's the best time to immediately stop using approaches that are not recommended.

Comment: how about that for a more modern version? :) http://jsfiddle.net/e6gYJ/13/

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well I'm so new that I haven't  got round to learning how to make input boxes, buttons, and outputs yet :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the "old code" is that you're using "Strict Equality Comparison" `!==` in the `while` condition that won't be met unless you cast the userChoice to a number since a prompt returns a string value. It would work if you use `!=` instead.

The problem with the "new code" has to do with closures, inside the `check` function a new local variable `userChoice` is created because you're passing an argument, that means that `userChoice` inside check is not the same `userChoice` that you declared outside, you can just remove the parameter and use the global variable you have defined:

```
var check = function() {...}
... 
var userChoice = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 100");
check();
```

Comment: Thats a very clear and helpful explanation of both questions, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've managed to find why the code gets into an infinite loop:

First:

```
var check = function(userChoice) { .... };
```

Inside this function, you are doing

```
userChoice = prompt("[...]");
```

This `userChoice` references the argument `userChoice` of the function. Thus, it cannot change the global `userChoice` you define below because it is an enterily different variable.

Second, you declare your global `userChoice`:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 100");
```

This creates a variable `userChoice` in the Global Scope and is assigned whatever the user enters in the prompt. **It might be a string!!**

Then, you execute your function check:  `check(userChoice);`

You pass the global `userChoice` as an argument, but inside your function, `userChoice` references the local `userChoice` and not the global one.

After you enter an integer value not greater than 100 nor lesser than 1, the while exits...

**At this time, the global `userChoice` is still the value you entered in the first place** because you manipulated another variable (the local one).

Then, you execute the next while with the value you entered in the first place. If this value does not satisfy `userChoice !== randNumber`, enters the loop; checks if `userChoice > randNumber` or `userChoice < randNumber`.

If you entered a string, these three checks fail. Thus, creating an infinite loop.

**tl;dr - How to fix this**

Remove the argument of your check function so you do not create a local variable:

```
function check() {
    while ((isNaN(userChoice)) || (userChoice > 100) || (userChoice < 1) || (userChoice %1 !== 0)) {
        userChoice = prompt("Choose a number between 1 - 100", "It must be a whole number!");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the:

```
while(userChoice !== randNumber) {
```

The result of `userChoice` (the result of `prompt`) is a string and `randNumber` is a number.

So if `randNumber` is `1` and the user enters `1` the result is still a string.
So the comparison is `1 !== "1"` which is `true`.

Because of that you will always have an endless loop. (A number is always `!==` to a string).

You can change it to this:

```
while(userChoice != randNumber) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
(userChoice !== randNumber)
```

can never be false because "!==" means "Different but of same type" and prompt returns a string, not a number! So once you've guessed the number correctly the loop never ends. It only crashes once you've found the answer because before then the prompt slows the loop down.

Put

```
while(userChoice != randNumber)
```

and you'll be fine :)

Have a look at this slightly more modern version, too: http://jsfiddle.net/e6gYJ/13/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is your usage of !== vs. !=

When you use !==, you are explicitly matching the type AND value.

so

```
5 !== "5"; //will be true
5 !== 5; //will be false
```

whereas

```
5 != '5'; // will be false
```

Comment: Hahaha oh god, I can't quite believe it was that simple! I'm even more amazed that I didn't think to try! Thank you :)